# how to add a gap between cells in the heatmap in the Echart library?

Tags: echarts

I don't know how to add a gap between cells in the Heatmap Echart library.
What option I need to add for this problem?

I have this chart at this moment.
[image]

I want to add a gap between cells like in this image...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add gap between heatmap items by changing the `borderColor` of the [`itemStyle`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-heatmap.itemStyle) property.

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=heatmap-cartesian&code=PTAEAcCcFMBdYJbUgWgQcwHYHsYCgBjbTAZ1lAAtsBXSE0AXlAG09R3QByARgCYBDTgBou3QSM4DhXAMziuAFnmcArMoBs4th04B2ZQA5lATmXcADGbHDt7Hr3DSejiQ6cyXiz6pe2u6711vA29jbwtw7kc8AF0AbjwQCBh4JFQMHHwiUnIAE34AT3omVg4uAGV-WFp8gqcAMUgEWqcAFQpaEhahP04AdWhczGguwrbqEe6uAFliKc5y6kwW2ISkqDhEZDQsXGhCYjJQfNh-RhZmcxEr0BUYkUuRbif7lhvea9fH0BlPh5uFH83iIVEDvuowTddJCRAYYaBjPCLEjnqBeF8bnwRAoMU9fqBuLiCYCCUTuKCfmSIaAcf8ntDQOoyXCaWTEay6WibjIibxUTzObwPmjefi7g9UVCvqjJdKRMLzHKfmDUSTFRKQSqRNT1SxUQzdcxUSzDaj2aanjdxXqnqj0RqCcL7TaCfimQ7uCTjErybafdT3S7uAzdD6WQYfey-EreFaY6jrUb5cLQw7ePjncwFS8HsKZV8nWDhfjDcK1QXNaBS9qiyIDRXQCaG-aG8jKbnbfLW3nW_jvR3ibDWxSLK2A62GYm8yyp092bOuXWG3zscuncv8bSWCWlw98fyvhmwfiS4fscfK4a3RfQPW97Cc9uRC37wS46_uKqz47d0_XU8t2YfcSW4AU_19R1v24al-3AycoJnKCoyveUbkDID5S_V8hVXbD9y-NVH2YECRDA4j5TBElTweElyxoytCXoxlKLrFjGzY9lMxAgECM7DkWBA9cmNA3CBIA0TyIJEdAJA6lo2EhlGLEglw14gl5zU2NSM0_VNOLTTqJYCl3i-EciIpBVTNI7SHgpOijMvKzmKrJy7wc9iRVs58wRHHivIJfN_KxW4nJEt9QpJRMRwpVN3Ogv0goZdCRybIKNP8rT23cld-OYCyhOywzmB1Ii5LBalLIeakiupeziscqqaxcxrb3Kh9mpYGC2rfUq-MNOSCvq_9SRaz0bM6p47K-OSdWm-luu4VKJvU7rMqUoacszCrBoqt0YhiPwADoAFt-HAAAKAAzJYCEQYhQHOhBYGgY6AEpQAAbz8FJaEwFgnpeo1XgB47LmB57QfRUAAB9oa4FBOHiPAAF9XoSbBwDuv6mC-9hYGwbAABtEHAAAuT6_HAbASCehBiHJzh8eidhkZ6dh0CaXJydxjgKGgDAKFgBmVHMABSGwyiZhmLHF7RWe0AAPABBBWEBIbm_FgApwGgBmCCqaB0FwOo2Y4E5-HJqhOlN9gSHAQmnqVmALYpspbaoAB3cnYEgCY_GRuXTYKFW1Y1yXtd1rh9eeo3IBNvxzfJ2oSBt0A7Yd2AnegF2ebKEhPe9339jKAOWdNgA3NXqH4QnpjOsOOGOhBMHJq4_FOhXyeRPx9cJghqEJ_gACNCcjn2JlT3AkEwIWuCoJoAC9iFOQmJY4UfLtnzgCGgGfkDX9gh-weBsGO6WVFlsvtBIZAkHVlg_FzjhMH4Y7I84AAFG6KFAABhfhIC5APhwLWOsGZ8yqKdXwbtjhVBdubVO7BB5D2gITBuMD87YC9qAcexc3byxgSDcoWtR7oLdkfQByA-jNFgBQcmoI_BlAobkZAv8ia4AZgAYkujw4BV8YEvXABQfgNN75PzKEQkhkdxFu3zvwXIWCABChNaBdzbjAvOwiFEezYYTDhXBIDoCHvwc6NwzHXEOioV6nBGEcFLvg_22gDrIziEAA) is the full example:

```js
import * as echarts from 'echarts';

var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

// prettier-ignore
const hours = [
    '12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
    '7a', '8a', '9a', '10a', '11a',
    '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
    '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'
];
// prettier-ignore
const days = [
    'Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
    'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'
];
// prettier-ignore
const data = [[0, 0, 5], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 6, 0], [0, 7, 0], [0, 8, 0], [0, 9, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 11, 2], [0, 12, 4], [0, 13, 1], [0, 14, 1], [0, 15, 3], [0, 16, 4], [0, 17, 6], [0, 18, 4], [0, 19, 4], [0, 20, 3], [0, 21, 3], [0, 22, 2], [0, 23, 5], [1, 0, 7], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 4, 0], [1, 5, 0], [1, 6, 0], [1, 7, 0], [1, 8, 0], [1, 9, 0], [1, 10, 5], [1, 11, 2], [1, 12, 2], [1, 13, 6], [1, 14, 9], [1, 15, 11], [1, 16, 6], [1, 17, 7], [1, 18, 8], [1, 19, 12], [1, 20, 5], [1, 21, 5], [1, 22, 7], [1, 23, 2], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [2, 3, 0], [2, 4, 0], [2, 5, 0], [2, 6, 0], [2, 7, 0], [2, 8, 0], [2, 9, 0], [2, 10, 3], [2, 11, 2], [2, 12, 1], [2, 13, 9], [2, 14, 8], [2, 15, 10], [2, 16, 6], [2, 17, 5], [2, 18, 5], [2, 19, 5], [2, 20, 7], [2, 21, 4], [2, 22, 2], [2, 23, 4], [3, 0, 7], [3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0], [3, 4, 0], [3, 5, 0], [3, 6, 0], [3, 7, 0], [3, 8, 1], [3, 9, 0], [3, 10, 5], [3, 11, 4], [3, 12, 7], [3, 13, 14], [3, 14, 13], [3, 15, 12], [3, 16, 9], [3, 17, 5], [3, 18, 5], [3, 19, 10], [3, 20, 6], [3, 21, 4], [3, 22, 4], [3, 23, 1], [4, 0, 1], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 0], [4, 3, 0], [4, 4, 0], [4, 5, 1], [4, 6, 0], [4, 7, 0], [4, 8, 0], [4, 9, 2], [4, 10, 4], [4, 11, 4], [4, 12, 2], [4, 13, 4], [4, 14, 4], [4, 15, 14], [4, 16, 12], [4, 17, 1], [4, 18, 8], [4, 19, 5], [4, 20, 3], [4, 21, 7], [4, 22, 3], [4, 23, 0], [5, 0, 2], [5, 1, 1], [5, 2, 0], [5, 3, 3], [5, 4, 0], [5, 5, 0], [5, 6, 0], [5, 7, 0], [5, 8, 2], [5, 9, 0], [5, 10, 4], [5, 11, 1], [5, 12, 5], [5, 13, 10], [5, 14, 5], [5, 15, 7], [5, 16, 11], [5, 17, 6], [5, 18, 0], [5, 19, 5], [5, 20, 3], [5, 21, 4], [5, 22, 2], [5, 23, 0], [6, 0, 1], [6, 1, 0], [6, 2, 0], [6, 3, 0], [6, 4, 0], [6, 5, 0], [6, 6, 0], [6, 7, 0], [6, 8, 0], [6, 9, 0], [6, 10, 1], [6, 11, 0], [6, 12, 2], [6, 13, 1], [6, 14, 3], [6, 15, 4], [6, 16, 0], [6, 17, 0], [6, 18, 0], [6, 19, 0], [6, 20, 1], [6, 21, 2], [6, 22, 2], [6, 23, 6]]
    .map(function (item) {
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'];
});
option = {
  tooltip: {
    position: 'top'
  },
  grid: {
    height: '50%',
    top: '10%'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: hours,
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: days,
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  visualMap: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    calculable: true,
    orient: 'horizontal',
    left: 'center',
    bottom: '15%'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Punch Card',
      type: 'heatmap',
      data: data,
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      itemStyle: {
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderColor: '#fff'
      },
      emphasis: {
        itemStyle: {
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```